# mysql union Merge different columns

Tags: mysql

[image]
I want to remove the null value And move up the value from yesterday
But I don't know how to do it.

[image]
Full sql:

```
(SELECT
    COUNT(1) toDay, NULL AS yesterDay
  FROM
    bas_user
    
  WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(user_datetime) BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
          DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        )
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
    GROUP BY HOUR(user_datetime))
UNION
(SELECT
   NULL AS toDay,COUNT(1) yesterDay
  FROM
    bas_user
     WHERE  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(user_datetime) BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
          DATE_SUB(
            DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),
            INTERVAL 1 DAY
          )
        )
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
        
  GROUP BY HOUR(user_datetime)
  )
```

Comment: How do you know which row from the first query matches to the second query? For example, how do you know 10 matches 52, 8 matches 37, etc?

Comment: 需求是统计今天和昨天的新增用户数,合并到1个结果

Answer (score 0):

In order to merge the two result sets, you need a join key. For example, assume `user_id` is the join key of both.

```
-- Step 1 
create table user_today (
    user_id      int,
    today_count  int);
    
create table user_yesterday (
    user_id         int,
    yesterday_count int);
    
 
insert into user_today values (101, 10), (102, 20), (103, 30);
insert into user_yesterday values (102, 25), (103, 35), (104, 45);


-- Step 2
select COALESCE(t.user_id, y.user_id) as user_id,
       t.today_count,
       y.yesterday_count
  from user_today t
  left
  join user_yesterday y
 using (user_id)
 union
select COALESCE(y.user_id, t.user_id) as user_id,
       t.today_count,
       y.yesterday_count
  from user_yesterday y
  left
  join user_today t
 using (user_id);
```

Result:

```
user_id|today_count|yesterday_count|
-------+-----------+---------------+
    101|         10|               |
    102|         20|             25|
    103|         30|             35|
    104|           |             45|
```